# Re-playing HTML <audio> faster on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html5-audio, mobile-chrome

My web app has a dictionary. The audio of each word can be played via a text-to-speech service, which I place into the DOM like this:

```
<audio id="word-id" src="https://url_to_audio_on_another_server/word"></audio>
```

Not that I'd want to auto-play, but I know actual user-interactions (like button clicks) are required to trigger the start of audio/video on mobile devices. I've done that:

```
$(".wcc_play_container").click(function() { 
  $(".word-audio").get(0).play();
});
```

This works on desktop and mobile, but on mobile, it only works once (meaning: it will not play again, even if the button is clicked again).

To fix this, I learned that I need to .load() the file again in order for mobile browsers to play again. (Fortunately .load() just 'reloads' the sound file, but does not need to actually re-request it from the server, as desktop network inspector can confirm.) Instead of putting load after the play (which would throw an error because the async .play() would be interrupted), I just .load() each time before playing:

```
$(".wcc_play_container").click(function() {
  $(".word-audio").get(0).load();  
  $(".word-audio")[0].play(); 
});
```

I can now play multiple times on both desktop and mobile, but it's suuuuper slow mobile. On desktop, it plays instantly upon click. On mobile, it takes ~2-3 more seconds after clicking before it plays, every time.

Despite the network inspector showing nothing re-fetching from remote sever (I can't confirm on mobile), the time delay makes me suspicious... But then, even if it was re-fetching, these are very small ~2kb sound files coming over LTE or WIFI.

Another post said I could just set currentTime = 0, but that did not work without .load() again, which made `currentTime = 0` pointless.

You can experience the difference on my web app here. Blazing fast on desktop. Super slow on mobile (click the audio button):
https://www.hackchinese.com/words/127856

Comment: To me it looks like the baidu service you are using is throttling the speed on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could be wrong, but I don't think this is correct. Their documentation doesn't reference this limitation, and also I'm not sure how Baidu would even know the request was coming from mobile, as it is the same http GET either way.

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly what's happening, but when I open baidu link directly on my iphone it takes 1-2 seconds to play the sound. When I open it on the computer it plays immediately. Also when I upload the MP3 to my own server and open that link from the iphone, it plays immediately. They could use the browser identifier for that.